# Combination of X-frame-options and Allow-access-control-origin header

Tags: http, http-headers, x-frame-options

I have three websites:

- a.com
- b-dev.com
- b-tst.com

I want to put website B in an iframe on site A. This works for b-dev but not for b-tst. After examining the response headers for b-dev and b-tst I noticed that BOTH of them have the header `X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` but only b-dev (the one that works) has `Allow-access-control-origin: *`. I want to draw the conclusion that the X-frame-options headers is ignored because of the other header. Is this correct?

We would like to change the response header to be a bit more secure. Would it be possible to change the asterisk to "a.com" to keep the existing behaviour but only for website A?